# Moq - using It.Is<> when passing parameters vs not using it

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

In which cases it is crucial to use It.Is<> syntax when passing parameter to Moq setup, instead of retrieving the value of such parameter separately, and then passing it in a "plain" way? So far my testing needs could have been limited, but I did not come across a need to use It.Is<> which could not be defined outside of the mock.Setup? It.Is<> looks very popular when I look through sources, also for such basic examples, so I wonder what would be the advantage. Below is simple example for brevity, but also with other cases I came across it did not make any difference. I mean:

```
mockRepo.Setup(m =>m.GetAllReadingsOn
(latestDate)
.Returns(_filteredReadings);
```

vs.

```
mockRepo.Setup(m => m.GetAllReadingsOn
(It.Is<DateTime>(d => d ==_latestDate)))
.Returns(_filteredReadings);
```

Comment: Using a concrete value means you limit the call to this concrete value. It.Is on the other hand can match multiple (or even arbitrary) values. Frankly, concrete values are not used often and you could possibly elaborate more on what you understand by "retrieving and passing in a plain way".

Comment: `d => d ==_latestDate` is a very basic example. You could do much more interesting things here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would always use the first approach as it is shorter. There's one exception: reference types which cannot be compared against because the method under test creates them. In this case you will need to compare property by property to ensure that the method created and passed a correct reference type:

```
mockRepo.Setup(m => m.GetAllReadingsOn(It.Is<SomeComplexObject>(x => 
    x.Foo == "foo" && 
    x.Bar == "bar" && 
    x.Baz == 123)))
.Returns(_filteredReadings);
```

This being said using this approach with value types such as DateTimes is a complete waste of keystrokes.

---

As requested in the comments section here's a basic example when the first approach will not work. Suppose we want to test the following method:

```
public SomeResult FooBarBaz()
{
    var myModel = new SomeComplexObject();
    myModel.Foo = "foo";
    myModel.Bar = "bar";
    myModel.Baz = 123;
    var result = repository.GetTheResult(myModel);

    return result;
}
```

Now obviously if you try to write the following test it will fail miserably:

```
// arrange
var sut = new Sut();
var myModel = new SomeComplexObject();
myModel.Foo = "foo";
myModel.Bar = "bar";
myModel.Baz = 123;
var expected = new SomeResult();
mockRepo
    .Setup(m => m.GetAllReadingsOn(myModel)
    .Returns(expected);

// act
var actual = sut.FooBarBaz();

// assert
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
```

Comment: thank you Darin, could you share a basic example when the first approach would not work?